# How to be more effective in the end game?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I usually end up getting to the top 20ish of the game and the circle starts to get really small. At this stage I've found I'm most effective if I stay near the edge of the circle and move my way in with it. However, I usually find I get shot in the back trying to do this or get picked off when moving in.

I've found a few tactics so far but have been unable to put any of them to great use:

1. Stay near the edge of the circle and move in with it.
2. Camp inside the zone in a building or near a rock and pick off players moving in late.
3. Guess the centre of the smaller circles and hide near it hoping to camp it out.
4. Constantly move around and try and pick players off.

How can I be more effective in the end game?

Answer (score 4):

Everything depends on the weapons and stuff you have.

I suggest that you not use a car since you will become an easy target, but even on this I saw people winning shooting people with their car.

The best option would be to have some automatic weapon and something comparable to a sniper (or at least an AR with a x4 scope).

Turn around the blue circle toward the white circle and kill people you encounter if you can or if you can do it without being spotted too much.

The use of silencers are greatly advised.

Also, make sure you take part in people killing eachother.
For example, don't shoot at a guy being shot, but shoot the guy shooting at him.
Sometimes it's good to let him finish his target before killing him, so you don't have the target turning back on you.

The biggest word is silence and avoidng being flanked by someone.
Always be aware of what's happening around you and take the most advantageous position (something safe and with possibility to take intel from it).

Also avoid going into small cabins, since you will probably receive a grenade in there or die leaving the cabin.

**As a summary:**

- Silence
- Get information
- Take opportunities
- Place well
- Move when necessary (especially since gas moves a lot end game)

All depends on your decision making and your placement.

Comment: Just want to make the point of **being silent** and **not joining other people fights** really important point. Sometimes not shooting anyone can get you in the top 2 quite easily, if u are able to play in that way.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a ton of wins and I'm not a specialist on PUBG but here is what I do when I play.

1. Every time I a lobby I ask myself: Will I play safe or go aggro?
2. With the safe/aggro mindset I start to draw my strategy. Go to a place with 100% car spawn, go to a high looting area, go for early air drops and so on...

When I reach the top 30 it's all about decision making. If I decided to go aggro, in that case I'll must likely have a car, I keep roaming the edges of the boarder and, after the 3rd closing event of the zone, I run straight to the middle of the zone and try to find a tree or rock to have some decent cover and pick players up. On the other hand if I decided to play safe, I'll must likely not have a car, so I just play prone on the edges and try to stay there as much as I can till I have to run to the new edge.

Keep in mind that the guns you get will influence on how you play the match as well, a lot of people like to have a rifle like AK of M14 and a Shotgun, I prefer the rifle + sniper rifle combo, like a M14 + Kar98k.

You can see the loot and spawning areas [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRAzJ.jpg).

Hope I could help you.

Comment: The OP asked about end-game effectiveness not how to reach it